# AngularJS data not being presented in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and am working on my first Plunkr.  When a user performs a search (from main.html, the corresponding controller is MainController), the correct view is being presented (user.html), but the data from the controller (UserController) is not being passed to the view.  What am I doing wrong?

Here the link to the code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OcfB6tBB36qWO9MiZ9CI?p=preview

Layout page (Index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/latest/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>
    <script src="UserController.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>GitHub Viewer</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Main page (main.html)

```
<div>
  {{ countdown }}
  <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
    <input type="search" required="" placeholder="User name to find" ng-model="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

User details page (user.html)

```
<h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
{{ error }}
<div><img src="{{ user.avatar_url }}" title="{{user.name}}"> Order:
  <select ng-model="repoSortOrder">
    <option value="+name">Name</option>
    <option value="-stargazers_count">Stars</option>
    <option value="+language">Language</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Stars</th>
      <th>Repos</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:repoSortOrder">
      <td>{{ repo.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ repo.stargazers_count | number}}</td>
      <td>{{ repo.language }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

MainController.js - controls main.html:

```
var app = angular.module('githubViewer');

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, $interval,
                                   $log, $anchorScroll, $location) {

  $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";

  $scope.search = function(username) {
    $log.info("Searching for " + username);
      if(countdownInterval) {
        $interval.cancel(countdownInterval);
        $scope.countdown = null;
      }
      $location.path("/user/" + username);
  };

  var countdownInterval = null;

  var startCountdown = function() {
    countdownInterval = $interval(decrementCountdown, 1000, $scope.countdown);
  };

  var decrementCountdown = function() {
    $scope.countdown -= 1;
    if($scope.countdown < 1) {
      $scope.countdown = null;
      $scope.search($scope.username);
    }
  };

  $scope.username = "angular";
  $scope.countdown = 5;
  startCountdown();

});
```

UserController.js (controls user.html) -- this is where it seems to fail.

```
var app = angular.module('githubViewer');

app.controller("UserController", UserController);

var UserController = function($scope, $log, $http, $routeParams) {

  var onUserComplete = function(response) {
    $scope.user = response.data;
    $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
    .then(onRepos, onError);
  };


  var onRepos = function(response) {
     $scope.repos = response.data;
     $location.hash("userDetails");
     $anchorScroll();
  };

  var onError = function(reason) {
    $scope.error = "Could not fetch the data";
  };

  $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
  $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
  $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
      .then(onUserComplete, onError);

};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I commented out the following line in UserController, but it still fails.     //var app = angular.module('githubViewer');

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about that. Your issue is a function hoisting one. You **can't** use `.controller('UserController', UserController)` **before** `var UserController = function(...`. If you change it to `function UserController(...`, it will work or simply declare `UserController` in the same was as `MainController`

Comment: All fixed here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/KjomRAZbaCQ10L8E6Cu1?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!  If you put it in the form of an answer I'll accept it.